# php login gives ?>

Tags: php, sql-server, authentication, login-script

i was trying to write a php login script. when i upload it to my webpage it show this: ?>

I am lost, i tried googling and reading abt php errors and even tried to look at my code many times but i cant figure out whats going on.

```
<?php

$host = 'myhost';
$user = 'user';
$pass = 'mypass';
$db = 'dbname';

$connect = mssql_connect($host,$user,$pass) or die('Unable to connect');
$database = mssql_select_db($db,$connect) or die('Unable to connect to selected database');

?>
```

This is my code for the connect with database part. The portion that has the form seems to work. but when i hit register, it just doesnt work. Hope you guys can help. Thanks.

Cheers 
Kums

Comment: Sounds like PHP is not setup properly. Before you try database connections, give phpinfo() a shot to verify PHP is working.

Comment: hi kichik, i tried it. it gives me a list of information abt my server. so you mentioned maybe "PHP is not setup properly". can you give me an idea of what in the list of information should i check to verify things are setup right?

Comment: If the list shows, PHP is installed properly. What do you expect the original page to actually show? Nothing at all is printed in your code.

Comment: oki so, basically i called this function above in another function called register.php. the code above i saved it as form.php. so i typed     <?php                                                                       include('connect.php');                                                    and then i wrote a form that takes user input for registration and saves it in the database. but once the input is keyed in, when i press register and it is supposed to reply whetehr it failed or succeeded. but when i click it, the page stays the same as in still in the registration form

Comment: so i thought maybe the code that connects to the database is wrong. so i just uploaded it and tried to see if it works. but the thing is when i uploaded and access the page all it shows is: ?>  So i am wondering if that means, does it mean it act connects to the server n db or does not? and i want to be sure it does becos at least then i will know whr i went wrong, whetehr the code to connect to the server or the registration form.

Comment: i couldnt post the registration form, the page says its too long by 400 characters. but do you knw roughly what does it mean if the registration page just sort of 'hangs'? thanks and i know i am asking a lot but i just started learning php 3 weeks ago. so i appreciate your help.    P.S there is a error in my comment, the code above was saved as connect.php and not form.php

Comment: and even when i upload to my server a php code that says for example    <?php                                                                       echo 'hi';                                                              ?>      the page only displays ?>.    it doesnt display hi at all. i am using kompozer. any chance thats the issue or smtg?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **PHP may not be properly configured on the webserver.**

Try running this code and see if you get the output.

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

Happy coding !